# JQuery not work in IE 8 or 7

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have this site here http://jamessuske.com/freelance/seasons/index.php and in the navigation on the left, I am using jQuery to remove a class and add it the current pages its on, also if you click on the `Menu` link it should show a submenu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( '.navigation li a' ).each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
    $('.navigation li ul.menu-submenu').hide();
    $('.navigation li a').eq(6).addClass("active");
</script>
```

Above is the code I have in every separate page to update the navigation.

In my header.php file, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
    var theWindow = $(window),
        $bg = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio = $bg.width() / $bg.height();
    function resizeBg() {
        if ((theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio) {
            $bg.removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $bg.removeClass()
                .addClass('bgwidth');
        }
    }
    theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");
});
</script>
```

Would this mess up my navigation?

The header.php file is included on all pages with php include.

Comment: jQuery 2.x has dropped support for old IE versions. Use jQuery 1.10.x instead.

Comment: AFAIK, jQuery 2 does not support IE 7 or 8.

Comment: Why do you trigger `resize` on the window when it's already occured?

Comment: Rob W...put it into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @user2499454 Additonal to jQuery version, in IEs you need to place document type declaration at the very first line in the file, and it must not preceed by any characters.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 2.x has dropped [support for old IE versions](http://jquery.com/browser-support/). Use jQuery 1.10.x instead.  Credit to Rob W.